# What are the rules for pinging someone in comments?

Tags: discussion

In my comments to [Can (quantum) angular momentum $L$ be zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98899/can-quantum-angular-momentum-l-be-zero) I tried to @PPG, but it won't let me. Presumably the conditions for whether or not I can ping someone are listed somewhere ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rather lengthy conditions are given on Meta.SO: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) In particular, these two points explain that `@`-pinging is both unnecessary and auto-deleted in your case - both you and the author of that post will ping each other automatically:

> If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is forgotten.
>
> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment. There is no need to use @name to notify them. (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.)

Comment: Aha! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 9):

The owner of a post is always pinged, so you don't need to explicitly mention it (and thus autocomplete doesn't work).

For that matter, editors of a post, closing moderators (not 3k users), and bounty-givers can also be pinged, though they don't turn up in the autocomplete.

Comment: Thanks Manish :-) Is there a list of ping rules anywhere?